# Ошибка при запуске кода JavaScript в Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js

Решил попытать счастья в js, но текстовый редактор мне подсовывает ошибку ...

```
alert("text")
^
ReferenceError: alert is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Code\script:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Как это исправить и запустить код через node.js ?

Comment: это весь код скрипта?

Comment: @highpassion да

Answer (score 4):

Функцию `alert()` предоставляет только среда исполнения JavaScript в браузерах. Попробуйте `console.log("text")`, она есть и в браузерах, и в Node.js. Только выводит она текст не в диалоговом окне, а в консоли (в браузерной консоли в DevTools или в обычной системной консоли).

Comment: Лучше уж в консоли чем постоянная ошибка

Comment: @user409986 Ну, на самом деле `alert()` это метод `window`, то есть это `window.alert()` — а в Node.js нет глобального объекта `window` со всеми его свойствами и методами, там другой глобальный объект и другое API.